# I need to display the sum of rows via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to display the sum of rows via AMPScript.

I am able to display rows like

```
Row 1  50
Row 2  60
---------
Row 3 110 (need to get the sum)
```

Here is the code:

```
%%[
Var @rows

set @rows = Lookup("CampaignNAME0_DE","Shares_Held__sum","Security_name_or_symbol","IBM")

var @searchtermlookupValue
set @searchtermlookupValue = "IBM" 

var @ReturnRows
set @ReturnRows = 0 /* Use 0 to get all results */

var @GetRows
set @GetRows = LookupOrderedRows("CampaignNAME0_DE",@ReturnRows,"Shares_Held__sum asc","Security_name_or_symbol", @searchtermlookupValue) 

var @GetRow, @GetRowCount
set @GetRowCount = rowcount(@GetRows)

if @GetRowCount > 0 then 

    var @GetRowNumber,@total
    set @total = 0

    for @GetRowNumber = 1 to @GetRowCount do 

            set @GetRow = row(@GetRows,@GetRowNumber) 

            var @Shares_Held__sum
            set @Shares_Held__sum = field(@GetRow,"Shares_Held__sum") 

            if @i == 1 then
              outputline(concat("<ul>"))
            endif
    ]%%
            <li>
               %%=v(@GetRowNumber)=%%&nbsp;<b>%%=v(@Shares_Held__sum)=%%</b>
            </li>

    %%[
            if @i == @rowcount then
              outputline(concat("</ul>"))
            endif

    next @i 

    ]%%

    Total of Shares_Held__sum %%=v(@total)=%%

%%[ else ]%%

---- No rows found ----

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your code and for loop were not looping as per the RowCount. I have trimmed lots of your code and now it should work.

```
%%[
SET @Data = LookupOrderedRows("CampaignNAME0_DE",0,"Shares_Held__sum asc","Security_name_or_symbol","IBM")

IF RowCount(@Data) > 0 Then 
    FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@Data) DO
        SET @Shares_Held__sum = Field(Row(@Data,@i),"Shares_Held__sum")

        IF @i == 1 Then
          outputline(concat("<ul>"))
        EndIF
]%%

Use this for row number: %%=v(@i)=%% 
Use this for Shares_Held__sum: %%=v(@Shares_Held__sum)=%%

<li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ebeced;">
    %%=v(@i)=%%&nbsp;<span style="color:#5c656e;"><i><b>%%=v(@Shares_Held__sum)=%%</b></i></span>
</li>

%%[
        IF @i == RowCount(@Data) Then
          outputline(concat("</ul>"))
        EndIF
    Next @i     
Else    
]%%
Total of Shares_Held__sum %%=RowCount(@Data)=%%
<!-- If search term does not match with the data for any record in data extension -->
---- No rows found ----
%%[EndIF]%%
```

Comment: Where are you totaling the shares held?

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing where you're actually adding numbers together.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
%%[
var @rows, @rowcount
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("CampaignNAME0_DE",0,"Shares_Held__sum asc","Security_name_or_symbol","IBM")
set @rowcount = RowCount(@rows)

IF @rowCount > 0 Then 

    var @row, @totalShares, @Shares_Held__sum
    set @totalShares = 0

    FOR @i = 1 TO @rowCount DO

        set @row = Row(@rows,@i)
        set @Shares_Held__sum = Field(@row,"Shares_Held__sum")
        set @totalShares = add(@totalShares, @Shares_Held__sum)

        IF @i == 1 Then
          outputline(concat("<ul>"))
        EndIF
]%%

<li>
%%=v(@i)=%%<b>%%=v(@Shares_Held__sum)=%%</b>
</li>

%%[
        IF @i == @rowCount Then
          outputline(concat("</ul>"))
        EndIF

    Next @i  

    outputline(concat("<br>totalShares: ", @totalShares))

Else    
]%%

<br>no rows found

%%[endif]%%
```